# pandas two dataframes, some sort of merge

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have two dataframes like this:

```
df['one'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
df['two'] = [nan, 15, nan, 22, nan]
```

I need some sort of join or merge which will give me dataframe like this:

```
df['result'] = [1,15,3,22,5]
```

any ideas?

Comment: Another option: `df.two.fillna(df.one)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to do it. So if `df.two` is `NaN`, you use `df.one`'s value, otherwise use `df.two`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your data
# ========================================
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(one=[1,2,3,4,5], two=[np.nan, 15, np.nan, 22, np.nan]))
print(df)


   one  two
0    1  NaN
1    2   15
2    3  NaN
3    4   22
4    5  NaN    


# processing
# ========================================    
df['result'] = np.where(df.two.isnull(), df.one, df.two)


   one  two  result
0    1  NaN       1
1    2   15      15
2    3  NaN       3
3    4   22      22
4    5  NaN       5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pandas method `combine_first()` to fill the missing values from a DataFrame or Series with values from another; in this case, you want to fill the missing values in `df['two']` with the corresponding values in `df['one']`:

```
In [342]: df['result']= df['two'].combine_first(df['one'])

In [343]: df
Out[343]:
   one  two  result
0    1  NaN       1
1    2   15      15
2    3  NaN       3
3    4   22      22
4    5  NaN       5
```